# Matrix calculus: differentiate a row vector, rather than a column vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, matrix-calculus

From my matrix calculus books I understand that $\frac{d\textbf{u}(x)}{dx}$ is a column vector (I am using numerator layout here), where $\textbf{u}(x)$ is a column vector and $x$ is a scalar variable. However, what is the shape of the derivative if we are differentiating w.r.t a ROW vector? That is, what is the shape of $\frac{d(\textbf{u}(x))^T}{dx}$? Is it a row vector or column vector?

Also, is it true that $\frac{d\textbf{u(x)}}{d\textbf{x}}= \frac{d(\textbf{u}(\textbf{x}))^T}{d\textbf{x}}$? Here, the $\textbf{x}$ is a column vector but not a scalar.

Thank you very much!

Comment: It seems like you are taking the derivative component-wise, so for any matrix, the derivative would be the matrix whose entries are the derivatives of the respective entries (row or column vectors included). So, $du/dx = (du^T/dx)^T$

Comment: Thanks a lot, David Peterson! Yes, I'm taking derivative component-wise. I think your answer makes sense. How about when the variable is no longer a scalar, but a vector (this is my second question) ?

Comment: Your second question is probably the Jacobian. It involves partial derivatives.

Comment: yes it is a Jacobian. I just want to know whether the Jacobian needs to to be transposed if u(x) is a row vector.

Comment: $u'(x)$ is a matrix in general, depending on the dimensions of $u$ and $x$